# Bacterial genome annotation using Annovar

Tags: annotations, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

am writing my own pipeline in python in order to annotate bacterial genome MTB, am new in this field and am a bit lost , I converted my VCF to appropriate annovar input format, then i got stack, i have to use dbSNP to annotate SNP and hrv37 as the reference genome for annotation but dont really know the correct command format or what i really need to provide more. I read the manual but it is not really helping me. Anyone with experience in using Annovar to annotate bacterial genomes? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the code, to help us know more.

Comment: I would ask the question, and look for useful answers [here](https://www.biostars.org/). Also, [this page](http://annovar.openbioinformatics.org/en/latest/user-guide/gene/#create-your-own-gene-definition-databases-for-non-human-species) on the documentation may help

Comment: Thanks for the hint!